# Extracting specific files from a unknown archive file format

Tags: unpacking, binwalk

I'm trying to extract some binary blobs from a unknown archive format. (*.pakz).
I know this archive contains some `.xtreme` binary files that are the files I'm looking for. My goal is to extract those files from the archive.

By doing some research I've came across `binwalk`. So I've tried to extract some signature info from it. It returned me several blobs of LZMA compressed data.

f.ex, this is the first entries in the output of `binwalk`

```
    DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12            0xC             LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 1130064 bytes
1079006       0x1076DE        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 669520 bytes
1718248       0x1A37E8        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 807872 bytes
```

I assume these are parts of a single compressed file I should combine? So I tried extracting each individual files/blob with `carve` option. This outputs me several .7z files however many are missing. I don't know why, by using verbose and log command line options, it doens't output any errors but outputs LZMA blob addresses that are not extracted.

If I extract files I get several .xml files that give me useful information, f.ex, the path of the files I'm looking for but I still don't know from the path the start/end bytes of that file.

Does anyone has any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's worth trying the "foremost" data recovery tool as well, sometimes it's able to extract files that binwalk misses.